# Script to rename, move and compress images automagically

Tags: bash, shell, imagemagick

I'm trying to create a script on my Raspberry's Xbian that will "watch" a folder and compress any folders with images I saved there from Google Image Search.

What I want: The script will move all folders with " - Google Search" in their name to a temp folder, rename them removing the " - Google Search" part, leaving only the subject of the search query. Then, it will sequentially number the files in each folder using the folder name / the search query as their new name. So, "Random file.jpg" and "anoth3r_rand0m_file.png" will become "search_topic_01.jpg" and "search_topic_02.jpg".

Then, they'll be all moved to another folder, an "Incoming Images" one, where ImageMagick will do its magic on them, at the same time moving them to a "Ready Images" folder.

Still with me?

Here's what I got so far, from bundling stuff I found online together with my limited knowledge of Bash scripting:

```
echo "making temp"
mkdir /media/dBox/downloads/Xyma/temp
wait
echo "moving files"
mv /media/dBox/downloads/Xyma/*Google\ Search /media/dBox/downloads/Xyma/temp
wait
echo "renaming folders"
rename s/\ -\ Google\ Search// /media/dBox/downloads/Xyma/temp/*
wait
echo "renaming files"
for dir in /media/dBox/downloads/Xyma/temp/; do
if test -d "$dir"; then
    (
        cd $dir
        for file in *; do
            newfile=$dir.${file#*.}
            mv "$file" "$newfile"
        done
    )
fi
done
wait
echo "making ready subfolder"
mkdir /media/dBox/downloads/Xyma/temp/00_Unreg_Ready_Image_Folders
wait
echo "moving folders to ready folder"
mv /media/dBox/downloads/Xyma/temp/* /media/dBox/downloads/Xyma/00_Unreg_Ready_$
wait
echo "removing temp folder"
rmdir /media/dBox/downloads/Xyma/temp
```

...and let's just say "AAARGHRGHRGHHhh".

I'm sure that there must be an even simpler way, with, say, a five-word command and maybe two parameters, that will auto magically do everything and sprinkle it with stardust, or generally "a simpler and better way to do it", but it's currently slipping my mind.

So, I'm open to ideas and suggestions.
Any help? Anyone?

Help!

Comment: Looks fine for me, the way it works for you, is the best way.

Comment: Well, something **is** off, since if it finds that a directory already exists, it doesn't do what it's supposed to do, and instead starts moving files and folders from my home directory (!) to the target folder while renaming them.

Apart from that, it doesn't rename all images in a folder sequentially, but only one of them (?!).

I guess the problem lies somewhere in me not using asterisks / escaping spaces properly. Any help, anyone? Any ideas why it leads to problems?

Comment: You need quotes around the regex in `rename 's/\ -\ Google\ Search//' /media/dBox/downloads/Xyma/temp/*`.